# How to trigger a file download using cURL or wget

Tags: unix, curl, wget

I am looking to download a file on a website using a command-line tool. The file in question is downloaded when a user clicks on a button - however, there is no url attached to this button and there is no network activity when the button is clicked.

Is there a way for me to download this same file (it's JSON) using the command line?

Comment: Your question is too vague. You need to provide some more specifics. However, in general, I guess the file is preloaded, which is why you seem to see no network activity. I'd recommend looking at the network tab when loading the page to see what files are being downloaded

Comment: Yes, I realize that this is a pretty vague question. I guess it makes sense that some of the files are preloaded, but the way the download button works is that the user makes a bunch of selections and then clicks a button to download only the items that were selected. When this happens, the user gets a JSON containing the items they selected - so there must be some sort of calculation that goes on after the user makes their selections. I'm thinking it might be too difficult to recreate this action from the command line.

Comment: `there is no network activity when the button is clicked.` - then the file is generated by javascript. which means nobody can answer this question without inspecting the relevant javascript activated by clicking said button. and since you didn't post the javascript, nobody here will be able to come up with an answer.  find the javascript by going to the site and press Ctrl+U (Firefox or Chrome or Internet Explorer)

Comment: Okay, so looks like I was able to find that code that triggers the JSON download, pasted below (it's minified, but should still make decent sense). Would there be any way to call this function using cURL?
  
```a.downloadSet = function(b) {
        var c, d;
        b = b || a.set,
        c = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b)),

        k().save(c.metadata.name + ".json", JSON.stringify(c, null, "  "))
}```